# Exception during context initialization

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

My spring web-app reach an error at the init step :

- i use eclipse STS
- hibernate 5.x
- spring mvc
- gradle
- apache tomcat

Log

```
16:51:09.998 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityManagerFactoryBean' defined in tn.alveodata.studyink.configurations.DBConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    16:51:09.999 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3ecc315f: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,appConfig,DBConfig,mvcConfig,availabilityController,companyController,contactController,homeController,instructorController,loginController,profileController,skillController,attachmentDaoImp,certificationDaoImp,companyDaoImp,educationDaoImp,emergencyDaoImp,experienceDaoImp,identityDaoImp,interlocutorDaoImp,linkingDaoImp,mediaStorageDaoImp,personDaoImp,profileDaoImp,sectorDaoImp,attachmentServiceImp,certificationServiceImp,companyServiceImp,educationServiceImp,emergencyServiceImp,experienceServiceImp,identityServiceImp,interlocutorServiceImp,linkingServiceImp,personServiceImp,profileServiceImp,sectorServiceImp,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionAttributeSource,transactionInterceptor,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,getEntityManagerFactoryBean,getJpaVendorAdapter,getDataSource,txManager,exceptionTranslation,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcPathMatcher,mvcUrlPathHelper,mvcContentNegotiationManager,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,mvcResourceUrlProvider,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,mvcUriComponentsContributor,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,mvcViewResolver,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
    16:51:09.999 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'getDataSource'
    16:51:10.012 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityManagerFactoryBean' defined in tn.alveodata.studyink.configurations.DBConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1674)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
```

my DBConfig :

```
package tn.alveodata.studyink.configurations;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;



@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:database.properties" })
public class DBConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lcemfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(getJpaVendorAdapter());
        lcemfb.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        lcemfb.setPersistenceUnitName("studyinkJpaPU");
        lcemfb.setPackagesToScan("com.dom.entities");
        lcemfb.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return lcemfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter getJpaVendorAdapter() {
        JpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        ((HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) adapter).setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbase");
        dataSource.setUsername("dbase");
        dataSource.setPassword("dbase");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(
                getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "tn.alveodata.studyink.utils.DomainPhysicalNamingStategy");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");

      return properties; }
}
```

in my dao classes in inject the em. using
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

Comment: You've got a problem with your Hibernate configuration. Look at the bottom of an error message, your database metadata seems to be invalid.

Comment: @Prokhorov, thx please can you help more cause i have not fixed it till now my entities seams to be correct implemented. have also verify my db too

Comment: [Here is the code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java#L1674) that produces your exception. Look closely at it, and then think about where does your entity declare invalid foreign key relation. Possibly an annotated property that doesn't actually link to an entity.

Comment: thx all my entities are now correctly implemented, errors deals with @MapsId